# Showing the same result in Rock Paper Scissors - Java Script

Tags: javascript

**I am trying to create rock paper scissors in java script and The below is the code I am executing, It is showing "The match is draw! play again" everytime. What goes wrong?

First taking the user input and checking the correctness. Generating the computer input by Math.random and assigning them RPS based on the output. Finally comparing both to determine the winner.**

```
const getUserChoice = function(userInput){
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
  if (userInput === 'rock'|| userInput ==='paper'|| userInput ==='scissors'){
    return userInput;
  }else {
    console.log('Error');
  }
}

userChoice = getUserChoice('rock'); 
console.log(getUserChoice('rock'));

const getComputerChoice = function(){
  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
  switch(randomNumber) {
    case 0:
    return 'rock';
    break;
    case 1:
    return 'paper';
    break;
    case 2:
    return 'scissors';
    break;
    default:
    return 'error';
  }
}

computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
console.log(getComputerChoice());


const determineWinner = function(userChoice, computerChoice){
  if (userChoice === computerChoice){
    return 'The match is draw! Play again.';
  }
  if (userChoice === 'rock'){
    if (computerChoice === 'paper'){
      return 'you lost';
    }else{
      return 'you won';
    }
  }
   if (userChoice === 'paper'){
    if (computerChoice === 'rock'){
      return 'you won';
    }else{
      return 'you lost';
    }
  }

  if (userChoice === 'scissors'){
    if (computerChoice === 'rock'){
      return 'you lost';
    }else{
      return 'you won';
    }
  } 
    }

console.log(determineWinner());**strong text**
```

Answer (score 2):

On your bottom line, you are not passing any parameters through.

Change it to:

```
console.log(determineWinner(userChoice, computerChoice));**strong text**
```

Currently, the first line of your determineWinner function is checking if null is equal to null (which it is), so is returning a draw.

Comment: Thanks chris, It Partially works. Now it is showing the other results as well. But, sometimes it is showing wrong results. For Example, userchoice is rock and computerchoice is paper, it is still showing you won, instead of you lost.

Comment: I don't know why this happens. Logically, it looks fine. Try adding in some console logs and printing out variables at certain times, to see if they are equal to what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Checkout the below answer:

```js
const getUserChoice = function(userInput){
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
  if (userInput === 'rock'|| userInput ==='paper'|| userInput ==='scissors'){
    return userInput;
  }else {
    console.log('Error');
  }
}

const userChoice = getUserChoice('rock');

const getComputerChoice = function(){
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  switch(randomNumber) {
    case 0:
    return 'rock';
    break;
    case 1:
    return 'paper';
    break;
    case 2:
    return 'scissors';
    break;
    default:
    return 'error';
  }
}

const computerChoice = getComputerChoice();

const determineWinner = function(userChoice, computerChoice){

console.log('user choice: ', userChoice);
console.log('computer choice: ', computerChoice);

  if (userChoice === computerChoice){
    return 'The match is draw! Play again.';
  }
  if (userChoice === 'rock'){
    if (computerChoice === 'paper'){
      return 'you lost';
    } else {
      return 'you won';
    }
  }
   if (userChoice === 'paper'){
    if (computerChoice === 'rock'){
      return 'you won';
    }else{
      return 'you lost';
    }
  }

  if (userChoice === 'scissors'){
    if (computerChoice === 'rock'){
      return 'you lost';
    }else{
      return 'you won';
    }
  }

    }

console.log(determineWinner(userChoice, computerChoice));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simply because you are not passing the arguments to the `determineWinner` function.

Change the last line to:

```js
determineWinner(userChoice,computerChoice);
```

Currently it's considering both choices as null and returning you the output as draw!